# Storing time SQlite Android

Tags: android, sqlite, unix-timestamp

Is there an accepted practice for storing time in a SQLITE database for Android?

For example the Unix timestamp stored as a real?

Comment: What does your timestamp looks like ?

Comment: long unixTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;

Comment: Well , you can store that in a column of type long then.

Comment: There is no long in sqlite

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: You can  have long type column - "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl(id integer primary key on conflict replace, timestamp long); It will definitely work. I have used it multiple times.

Comment: @ShadabAnsari "long" solves to INTEGER. https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: But the timestamp can be stored in that. It will be sufficient for timestamp value.

Comment: Yes, you can. Even if I prefer storing dates (and/or times) as a TimeString. It's more readable, for me.

Comment: Well, sqlite's integer can be up to 8 bytes... Java's long is a 8 bytes integer(integer in terms of math not programming), too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two general ways to do it-  as an int (basically unix timestamp) or as a string, generally in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss order.  The advantage of the string is its human readable, and doing it in that format allows you to do a time comparison as a string compare without conversion (hours here should be 24 hour format).

Comment: What is the correct way to get the current time in "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" format via Java/Android?

Comment: You use a SimpleDateFormat to parse it into that form.

Comment: Like this? String curTime = (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")).format(new Date());

Comment: Or I guess "kk" instead of "HH" actually